# Apache session module does not work after restart

Tags: php, apache, session, wamp

Some PHP application is running on Apache 2.4.9 (from WAMP). Application requires sessions support. After apache installation all session mods are off so it did not work first.

Then I go and activate mod_session, mod_session_cookies, mod_session_crypto, mod_session_dbd => PHP application starts working.

Now restart the PC, start Wamp again - SESSIONS ARE NOT WORKING ANYMORE! Although all modules are active. No errors or warnings in logs.

The only solution I found so far - manually switch off all the session-related mods, restart apache, again manually activate all the modules, restart the apache and then it works again!

Any ideas how to make it work always?

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing in the error log? Have you checked if anything weird is going on with where apache puts your session files?

Comment: Checked the location for session files: they are even created when I start using application. No further error messages found ;(

Comment: In which way are they "not working anymore"? Maybe they are but you got something else wrong?

Comment: Unless you are doing something very specific **none of those Apache module are required** for PHP sessions to work. Please show some of the PHP code that uses sessions so we can see what you are **actually doing.**

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly - good to know that. This is not my code but some third-party cms. I have found some diag php script of this CMS, disabled all session modules and script shows me that sessions are enabled. After I deactivated all modules it works again but I have to observe for how long.